# Force Div below another and prevent overlap

Tags: css, layout, html

I have two Div elements. The first should be 100% height and width of the screen. I would like the second Div to be 100% width but variable height depending on the contents and to start inline (below the first). So the full screen is Div 1 and you have to scroll down to see Div 2. But everything I have tried they overlap.

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:100%;width:100%;left:0px;top:0px"></div>
<br/>
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;background-color:yellow">
      <br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>..
</div>
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ8h/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Becasue

```css
position:absolute
```

makes the div non-occupy, which means other elements don't "see" them when aligning and positioning.

Use this:

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
div.div2 {
    top:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ8h/1/)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to set the html- and body-tag to height: 100%:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

And the second thing, you have to change is to set the position of the first div to "relative" and not to "absolute" (as it is in the jsfiddle-file):

```
position: relative;
```

I hope it helps...

EDIT:
And remove the `<br>`-Tag between the two divs - if not, there will be a white gap between them...

Answer (score 2):

Use should use "clear:both" ... add the following between the div tags

```
<style>
.clearfix{
clear:both;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<body>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Problem is position: absolute attribute.